# handle incorrect values in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

HI I have one doubt in snow flake server.
how to handle non ascii value in snowflake

```
table : emp 

Empno|Empname
1    |ravÉi
2    |banu raju
3    |raḠu kumar
```

based on above data i want output like below

```
Empno|Empname
1    |ravEi
2    |banu raju
3    |raGu kumar
```

I have tried like below

```
select empno,uncode(empname,ecoding='utf-8')lname from emp
```

but above query throwing error:
sql compilation erro: error line 1 at postition 27 invalid identifier encoding

can you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in snow flake server .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing accents from string in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606576/removing-accents-from-string-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

did you try, it should work , the function Unicode returns the Unicode code point for the first Unicode character in a string.

```
select empno,empname from emp; 

select unicode('ravÉi')lname from dual;  will return the value
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working .it's showing results 76

Comment: you mean this query is returning you 76 , "select 'ravÉi' from dual;"

Comment: yes this query select unicode('ravÉi')lname from dual; returning numeric values

Comment: The UNICODE function of Snowflake will return Unicode code point of the first Unicode character in a string  this is different than what you want,  I don't think the Unicode function will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input and output what you really want is to replace Unicode characters with their closest ASCII equivalent.

A JS UDF in Snowflake can help you do that:

You can solve this with a JS UDF in Snowflake:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normalize_js(S string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS 'return S.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")'
;

select normalize_js('áéÉña');

-- 'aeEna'
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66606937/132438.